# Chome Extension unable to edit DIV on main page and DIV inside iFrame page at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've come across a strange issue with **Google Chrome Extension** where I can edit a DIV inside the main page. I can also edit a DIV located inside an iFrame off the main page (different URL inside the iFrame), however I'm unable to edit both DIVs at the same time. I can't explain this and was wondering if this might be a bug or something I'm doing wrong.

Here is my manifest file (manifest.json)

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Replace",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "all_frames": true,
            "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*","<all_urls>"],
            "exclude_matches": [],
              "js": ["replace.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my javascript (replace.js)

```
// Elements on the main page
document.getElementById('productSelectorTab').innerHTML = '<div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Hello World</div>';
document.getElementById('downloadCenterTab').innerHTML = '<div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Hello World</div>';

// Elements within an iFrame
document.getElementById('product0').innerHTML = 'XB4BV31 Hello World';
document.getElementById('product1').innerHTML = 'XB4BV33 Hello World';
```

Here is the page I'm using to test this extension.

http://www.schneider-electric.com/products/au/en/4800-pushbuttons-switches-pilot-lights-control-stations-joysticks/4840-pushbuttons-switches-pilot-lights/632-harmony-xb4/?BUSINESS=1

When you have installed the extension you will notice two TABs in the left side navigation now say 'Hello World'. But the other two elements are not changed.
So, comment out the first two lines of code in the js file (productSelectorTab & downloadCenterTab), reload the extension, reload the page and now the other two elements located inside the iFrame are now displaying Hello World.

I don't understand why I can't edit the main page and then the other separate page inside the iFrame at the same time. Hopefully someone can explain this issue and what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks everyone, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot install your extension without a link to your extension :-)

If the code lines in your post represent the full code of replace.js I have the following suspections:

1. Maybe you should wait for the page to finish loading by either using `window.onload` (or similar) or by using `"run_at": "document_end"` in your manifest
2. Probably the script produces an error when either the `productX` elements or the `XXXXXTab` elements don't exist. I guess they don't exist on both the main page and the iframe page, do they? In that case: Check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Devnull69, your point 2 was spot on! It was causing an error.
No change is needed to the manifest file, all we are doing is checking the ID exists before changing them.

Here is the fixed javascript (replace.js) as mentioned above.

```
// Elements on the main page
if(document.getElementById('productSelectorTab')){
   document.getElementById('productSelectorTab').innerHTML = '<div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Hello World</div>';
};
if(document.getElementById('downloadCenterTab')){
   document.getElementById('downloadCenterTab').innerHTML = '<div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Hello World</div>';
};

// Elements within an iFrame
if(document.getElementById('product0')){
   document.getElementById('product0').innerHTML = 'XB4BV31 Hello World';
};
if(document.getElementById('product1')){
   document.getElementById('product1').innerHTML = 'XB4BV33 Hello World';
};
```